# Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have Eclipse: `eclipse-jee-juno-win32`. I need to create Maven project with it, but the problem is, I have been searching how to install maven plugin or something, that I could be able to create maven projects. Unfortunately I can not find anything.

Can anybody provide me some information how to create maven projects in Eclipse? Previously I have been always using IntelliJ, but now I need to use Eclipse and it is been the first time I have run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1. In Eclipse, open Help/Eclipse Marketplace, then write maven. You will see maven integration for Eclipse. I don't like it because in my work we have too big projects for it. But if you have something small, it's probably the best choice.
2. Use manually building with WTP plugin.
   Add to your pom.xml:

pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
      <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And then in your root directory (where pom.xml exists)

> mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse

It creates all eclipse structure (with all jars included to your project). Then you just need to import existing project into workspace: File/Import/General/Existing project into workspace, choose directory with your project

Comment: For now I am working on a small projects. Your first solutions is just what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I have been using Maven for some time now and a very easy way to use it in Eclipse is:

1. Open Eclipse and go to: Help / Eclipse Marketplace
2. Insert on search: "Maven" and look for "Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP" and install it
3. If the installation was successfully made you should see in Window/Preferences the Maven option in the left.
4. After this I would advice you to download the last version from here: http://maven.apache.org/download.html and put it on a folder in C partition(or other partitions) - just remember that the path to the downloaded maven shouldn't contain spaces (you will have errors) - for example, my path is: "c:\Apache_Maven\apache-maven-3.0.4..."
5. When you download it, go in Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Maven (from left menu and expand it) -> Installations -> and add you path to the downloaded maven.
6. To create the project: New -> Other -> Maven -> Maven Project -> and search on filter the archetype you would like to use (for example: use maven-archetype-webapp for web application etc.). Click Next and put your project details: Group Id, Artifact Id, Version etc.
7. When you finished creating the project, the most important file is pom.xml. There you add your dependencies. Another important thing, your maven local repository will be created here: "c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\m2."
8. If you want to run maven install/build/clean etc, you right click on project and click "Run as" -> Select option

I hope these steps will help you start working with Maven. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know at least two ways:
1. install eclipse maven plugin m2eclipse: Help->Intall new software: work with: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases [enter]
2. execute `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart`. This will create basic maven project structure. Then, in folder where generated pom.xml is execute: mvn eclipse:eclipse
You can also execute `mvn archetype:generate` and chose one from hundreds of predefined project types (archietypes)

Answer (score 0):

You can download [Springsource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) (STS) and create template maven project.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install JBoss Tools, that has a Maven plugins set for various archetypes like JSF, Seam, Spring etc.  If you are on Indigo, go for JBoss Tools 3.3 Final and for Juno, go for JBoss Tools 3.7 or 4